# facebook-php-sdk: Why $name variable does not return nothing?

Tags: php, facebook

```
 require 'facebook.php';

    $app_id ="11111111111111111";
    $app_secret = "11111111111111111111111111";

    $facebook = new facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
    ));

    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
    $page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
    $page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
    $like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
    $country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
    $locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];
    $name = $signed_request["user"]["name"];
```

Comment: You'll never get user name within `signed_request`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [facebook docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/), the `user` property is

> A JSON object containing the `locale` string, `country` string and the `age` object (containing the `min` and `max` number range of the age) for the current user.

Note the lack of any mention of a `name` in there.

Comment: thank you for your answer, how can i get the name for current facebook user?

Comment: Dunno.  Doesn't look like you'll get it directly from a signed request, though.  The `user_id` might help if passed to a different API, but i don't know enough about the facebook API to tell you how to get a user's info.